# Issue with Intel GMA950 on Debian (read:Linux Mint/Ubuntu) Variant

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, freeze, linux-distributions

I have a Dell D420 on which I run Linux Mint Gloria. However every once in a while the laptop completely freezes up. First the GUI freezes, then a minute later the ssh session I had with the computer dies. I've heard of strange issues with the Intel GMA 950 chipset before and am now a little suspicious that it is the reason for the issues. In addition, every once in a while when I try to bring the computer back from sleep, it simply flashes its status lights at me like a BIOS error until I reboot.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I can go about narrowing down the issue, maybe go as far as resolving it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=30316&p=174718#p174718) the issue I'm running into is a well-documented bug in the kernel.

For those of you suffering from this bug as well take a look at [upgrading to the 2.6.30 Kernel](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=58&t=27963&st=0&sk=t&sd=a#p168308), which should fix these issues.